# How to solve the Problem of Database Seeder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using databaseeder to store the name of controller in the permissions table but i didnot why i am getting error.This table have a relation with roles table using belongsToMany relation. 
**Here is my Role.php**

```
public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class)->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

**Here is my Permission.php**

```
protected $fillable=['id','name','controller'];
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

And Here is my **databaseSeeder.php**

```
$superrole= Role::create([
            'name'=>'super admin',
        ]);
$permission_ids = [];
        $route_name = [];
        $controllers = [];
        foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route)
        {
            $action = $route->getAction();
            if (array_key_exists('as', $action)) {
                $route_name = $action['as'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists('uses', $action)) {
                $controllers = $action['uses'];
            }

             $permission_check = Permission::whereIn('name' , $route_name)
            ->whereIn('controller' , $controllers)->first();
             if(!$permission_check)
             {
                 $permission = new Permission;
                 $permission->controller = $controllers;
                 $permission->name = $route_name;
                 $permission->save();
                 $permission_ids[] = $permission->id;
             }
        }
       $superrole->permissions()->attach($permission_ids);
```

But when i try to run the db:seed iam getting this error[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHjc4.png)
Here is the dd($controllers)
[image]

and dd($route_name)
[image]

Comment: Check your `$controllers` var... Simply it's not an array

Comment: i updated my post with screenshots of dd() please check...

Comment: I don't know how you can get that result... First `uses` and `as` parameters are strings (or closures)... and since you're overriding `$route_name` and `$controllers` you should retrieve strings... and `whereIn` will become useless since you should use a simple `where`.... Second the `dd` should break the foreach loop at first iteration so, the array should contain only one result...

Comment: if i use where then it gives me following error..................SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter numb
er (SQL: select * from `permissions` where `name` = Facade\Ignition\Http\Control
lers\HealthCheckController@__invoke and `controller` = ? limit 1)

Comment: Man honestly what you're trying to do is a bad idea... If you change for some reason the route, or you add a route, you must reseed the whole permission table... you should check wheter `uses` is a string or a callback (that's why you're getting that error IMO)... With the [Gates and Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization) you don't need to keep trace of the controller... Think about it...

Comment: ok here right now midnight...i will let you update tomorrow and thanks for your time

Comment: thanks man for our time and show me the correct and easy path...now my system works great with policies.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: credit goes to you